# Inferring Generic Class in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class ClassWithHelper<T extends HelperInterface> {
    Class<T> helperClass;
    protected T helper;
        protected Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        public void loadHelper(String helperString) throws InstantiationException,        IllegalAccessException {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(helperString)) {
            wizard = gson.fromJson(helperString, getHelperClass());
        } else {
            wizard = getHelperClass().newInstance();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Class<T> getHelperClass();
}

public class ImplementingClass extends ClassWithHelper<HelperClass> {

    @Override
    protected Class<HelperClass> getHelperClass() {
        return HelperClass.class;
    }
}
```

Now, what is nice is that when I call implementingClass.helperClass, it automatically casts it to HelperClass.  However, I am wondering if I really need to write and override getHelperClass.  I can't write helper.getClass (because it might be null), and I know the way I have it written there is a type erasure problem.

However, is there a way for me to rewrite my code to avoid having to state the helperClass in two ways and still have type inference for it?

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to have the code nicely formatted?

Comment: Yes, better formatting would help. Also, some things seem to be missing from the code. Is T a type parameter for the ClassWithHelper class? Does ImplementingClass provide a type argument for T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
protected Class<T> getHelperClass() {
    final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    return (Class<T>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Comment: That works.  Brilliant code.  I'll have to figure it out later!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, unless you can reflect on `helper`, there is unfortunately *no* runtime type information available - generics are *strictly* a compile-time tool.

There are different ways you could do this - include the type as a parameter to ClassWithHelper's constructor instead of overriding a method, or force subtypes to provide `helperFromJSON` and `newHelper` method - if you think that looks better, but if you need the type at runtime, you do need to "state it in two ways".

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public abstract class ClassWithHelper<T extends HelperInterface> {
    Class<T> helperClass;
    protected T helper;
    protected Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public void loadHelper(String helperString) throws InstantiationException,        IllegalAccessException {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(helperString)) {
            wizard = gson.fromJson(helperString, getHelperClass());
        } else {
            wizard = getHelperClass().newInstance();
        }
    }

    public Class<T> getHelperClass() {
        return helperClass;
    }

    protected ClassWithHelper(Class<T> helperClass) {
        this.helperClass = helperClass;
    }

}

public class ImplementingClass extends ClassWithHelper<HelperClass> {

    public ImplementingClass() {
        super(HelperClass.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: That might be about as good as it gets.  In your way of writing it, you still have to write HelperClass twice.